# MySQL Three Table Join - User and friend pictures

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Have been trying for hours - unfortunately I'm stuck on this three-table join.

The problem is that I can retrieve all of a user's friend's photos. But I want the friend's photos AND the user's photos. However, I am unsure of the syntax for this.

Here is my table structure:

```
active_users: id, username, name, etc...
friends: relationship_id (PK), friend1_ID (FK), friend2_ID (FK), status
pictures: picture_id (PK), user_id (FK), name, date, etc.
```

So here's the statement I currently have to get a user's friend's photos:

```
SELECT p.*, a.username
FROM friends f
JOIN active_users a ON (f.friend_1ID='$userID' AND f.friend_2ID=a.id AND status=1)
JOIN pictures p ON (p.user_id=f.friend_2ID)
```

How might I modify this to include the user's photos? I can do it with a UNION, but I believe (or have been told) that this is expensive and prone to SQL attacks if there is a way in through user input.

I've also contemplated adding a user as a friend to himself - would this be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the join to join on friends or the user:

```
SELECT p.*, IF(p.user_id = friend_2ID, a.username,'$username')
FROM friends f
JOIN active_users a ON (f.friend_1ID='$userID' AND f.friend_2ID=a.id AND status=1)
JOIN pictures p ON (p.user_id=f.friend_2ID OR p.user_id = '$userID')
GROUP BY p.photo_id
```

Note that you should ensure $userID is escaped or, even better, use parameterised queries.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked. With the current DB structure it should only return 19 rows, and this returns 109 rows. Seems because our first join narrows down to our user's friends, and the second join then says choose an image in p for each user where the uploader is the friend OR the user. Also the data is escaped I've just place this here for brevity :)

Comment: @bgoers Ack. You're correct. This will repeat a users photos for all his friends. Michael's answer is a good bet in that case.

Comment: Seems this has been my problem all day though. I can narrow it down and retrieve friend pictures, but as soon as I start searching for user pictures in the same query, I start receiving duplicate rows. :(

Comment: @bgoers I've tweaked the query. It shouldn't give duplicate rows and should (hopefully) show the correct username.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Now the why - how does this work exactly? I'm not familiar with IF statements in SQL. Also, what is the group by accomplishing?

Comment: @bgoers The group just decides how to group the results. I.e. this stops the multipliying out of results. The if just says "If this is a friend use that friends username. Otherwise use the users username".

Comment: Guess I will just have to research the group by. I've accepted your answer as it works perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bgoers Sorry I was a bit vague. Definitely research the GROUP BY as it's very useful but essentially the GROUP BY only returns one row for each p.photo_id in the results. This removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an additional join against `pictures` - one to get the user's pictures, and one to get the friend's.  Alias them differently.

```
SELECT
  /* Note below about SELECT * here... */ 
  puser.*,
  pfriend.*,
  a.username
FROM 
  friends f
  /* We assume $userID is already validated and escaped */
  JOIN active_users a ON (f.friend_1ID='$userID' AND f.friend_2ID=a.id AND status=1)
  /* Join once for the user friend_1ID */
  LEFT JOIN pictures puser ON (puser.user_id = f.friend_1ID)
  /* And again for the friend friend_2ID */
  LEFT JOIN pictures pfriend ON (pfriend.user_id = f.friend_2ID)
```

Note it is going to cause you problems to use `*` in the select list here because the column names will be ambiguous when you fetch them. You will need to list out and alias the columns individually to disambiguate them:

```
SELECT
  puser.picture_id AS puser_picture_id,
  puser.othercol AS puser_other,
  pfriend.picture_id AS pfriend_picture_id,
  pfriend.othercol AS pfriend_other,
  a.username
FROM...
```

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this SQL is confusing. I think what's happening with this query is that it narrows down our users with the first join, then the second join returns EVERY picture for each user narrowed from the first join. So if I have 10 users and 20 pictures, it returns 200 results. The third query only narrows it down from there, but by that point it seems like its busted. Is it THAT big of an issue if I do a union?

Comment: @bgoers Busted in what way?  No it isn't that big a deal to use a `UNION`.  There are no security issues with them not already present in the query as a whole. But the UNION might take twice the time of the single query if it duplicates the work, whereas the JOIN might be a lot faster depending on your indexes.\

Comment: @bgoers Looking at it right now I realize the two joins against Pictures should probably be `LEFT JOIN` if either of the users have _no_ pictures.

Comment: I suppose I didn't mean busted as in it just fails. I do appreciate the help and thank you for your time. What ends up happening is that on the first join, we JOIN friends and active_users, which correctly retrieves a result set for a user's friends. Then, however, we have the second join which for some reason returns every picture for every user. So if I have 20 pictures and 10 users, it's a 200-row result set. It's basically returning each user picture result with a single username, instead of just excluding pictures not from the user

Comment: @bgoers What you describe is called a cartesian product - all rows of t1 multiplied by all rows of t2. That usually happens if there is no `ON` clause. I would expect it to return all pictures for all users that have a friend relationship with `friend_1ID`. Hard to say without sample data.

Comment: Strange, indeed. I tried copying and pasting your code directly into a phpmyadmin sql query, and the same result occurred. What's happening is that with a left join, it's grabbing all the correct pictures but it's combining this with the result set of the first join statement. That's why we have a cartesian product. Here it should not be joining both, but instead selecting from the second based on the results of the first, and I'm unsure how that might be accomplished :)